# Request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function to delete the first node in the linked list, but I am getting the following error:

```
prog.c: In function 'del':
prog.c:38:13: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
    head=head->next;
             ^
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
};

int length(struct node* head)
{
struct node* current=head;
int count=0;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    count++;
    current=current->next;

}
return count;
}

void push(struct node** head, int ndata)
{
struct node* new_node=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 new_node->data  = ndata;
  new_node->next = (*head);
  *head=new_node;


 }

void del(struct node** head)
{
if(head==NULL)
return;
else
{
struct node *temp=*head;
 head=head->next;     // Line 38
 printf("data del is %d\n", temp->data);
 free(temp);
}

}

int main()
{

struct node* head = NULL;

push(&head, 1);
push(&head, 3);
push(&head, 1);
push(&head, 2);
push(&head, 1);

printf("count of nodes is %d", length(head));
del(&head);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: line 38: *head=(*head)->next;

Comment: @Serge: that would need parens: `*head = (*head)->next;`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, correct. thank you. I am getting disappointed...

Comment: @Serge: thanks. it fixed the issue!

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) indent the code after every opening brace '{'. and unindent the code before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level (never use tabs) as 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
head=head->next;
```

is not correct because `head` does not point to the first entry in the list,

rather it points to the 'head' pointer, those contents point to the first entry in the list.

So you could possibly use:

```
*head = (*head)->next;
```